# JDBC for SQLCipher

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, sqlcipher

Is there any JDBC driver exist for SQLCipher? I want to write program with javaSE and encrypted SQLite. I searched on the Internet and found nothing much on SQLCipher JDBC.

Or any other free solution on encrypted SQLite beside using SQLCipher? I'm using JavaSE.

Comment: Does it have any ODBC driver?

Comment: I think It also doesn't have ODBC driver

Comment: So does it have a native c/c++ library? you may have a native(x) app to connect to the context with, then invoke the x from java app using JNA or JNI or CORBA.

Comment: There isn't a public JDBC driver for SQLCipher at this time. If you have a commercial requirement for a JDBC driver, please drop us a note at support@zetetic.net and we can discuss.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Apache 2.0 licensed package named `sqlite-jdbc-crypt` ("SQLite JDBC Driver with encryption and authentication support") available at https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt

Click on the 'Releases' tab in the center to download a pre-build .jar file.

Here's example Java code to create an encrypted SQLite database named `db.sql` which is encrypted with the password `apassword`:

```
package com.name.test;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        try (final Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite", "",
                "apassword")) {
            try (final Statement stmt = connection.createStatement()) {
                stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE test (data TEXT(10));");
                stmt.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES('hello');");
            }
            connection.close();
        } catch (final SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("finished");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fork of the JDBC driver for SQLite that modifies it to work with SQLCipher: [sqlcipher-jdbc on GitHub](https://github.com/decamp/sqlcipher-jdbc). You have to build it yourself, though.

When you built it, you get an JAR file that you have to provide in your project's classpath.

Comment: That says " (OS X only) "

Comment: > The only native binaries included here currently are for 64-bit OS X.