# encrypt sqlite database file using sqlcipher in java

Tags: java, sqlite, encryption, sqlcipher

I need to encrypt sqlite data base file using sqlcipher in java. I tried using sqlcipher.jar, but resulting in compilation problem

```
The type android.database.Cursor cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class file
```

Is there any way to encrypt or decrypt sqlite database file using sqlcipher in java?

Comment: Just to get this straight: You are on Java (SE?) **not** Android? For Android there are instructions: https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: I am not using android, its pure java application

Comment: Then you cannot use android.database.Cursor. If sqlcipher references that, you might be forced to look for another lib or a version of it that works with pure Java.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30662412/982149

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sqlcipher.jar, use the gradle for dependencies:

```
dependencies {
 ...

    implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:3.5.9@aar'
}
```

More details:
https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/