# Connect encrypted .sqlite file in netbeans

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

My code is un without a password but now I just encrypt SQLite file by using Db Browser and enter password `pjjf` so now how to connect it, now the old code is that how to pass the password

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:LiberaryNew.sqlite");
```

because

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:LiberaryNew.sqlite","pjjf");
```

not working

Comment: Did you use SQLCipher?

Comment: yes it is SQLciphr

Comment: Please answer me

i am A newbie

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170836/jdbc-for-sqlcipher

Answer (score 0):

JDBC doesn't support out of the box SQLCipher. Although you can use a modified version of the JDBC driver ([sqlcipher-jdbc](https://github.com/decamp/sqlcipher-jdbc)) from decamp that supports it. Yo